# Using geometry nodes to create air volumes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I need to create simple closed air room volumes to be used in thermal building simulations based upon 3D building geometries and thinking of the following method and would like some feedback since I have not used geometry nodes before. The volumes should be separated by floor slabs and internal walls, they should have more or less planar floor and consist out of planar closed faces. The model including air volumes (red transparent objects created in an other tool) can be found [here](https://github.com/maxtillberg/ICEBridge/blob/main/spaces.blend).

[image]

My idea is something like this:

1. Create a horisontal grid about 500 mm above each floor plan covering the entire building
2. Create a cube with some resolution, about 50mm and connect the grid and cube to instance of points
3. Use Raycast to trace the cubes up and down until they collide with a floor/roof. No collision or collisions with walls (for example in open door openings) will delete the cube. Other collisions, for example furniture and columns will be ignored.
4. Merge cubes next to each other into a single volume. I assume that the grid resolution is the same as the cube size.
5. Reduce sloping roofs and possible not ortogonal walls into larger surfaces (not sure how to do this, maybe merge by distance).

Any comments would be welcome, as I said I am new to geometry nodes and there are probably lots of ways to do this.

/Max

Comment: Hello ! I think up until step 4 this should be manageable. However I think for the "merging" part you'll have to use a boolean operation, which you will find for thousands of objects will make your CPU cry.

Comment: Do you want to only get the approximated volume as a value or do you want a mesh object to fully encompass the available volume ?

Comment: The problem is that if you want to trace cubes up and down you will add up additional volumes like in your example in balcony.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. I would like the volume as exact as possible but in this case the resolution would be 5 cm and that is fine. Regarding the boolean operation this is bad I guess a deal breaker. A would need to simulate buildings about 20x100m and that means about a million cubes per floor. I wonder if it would be possible to merge the cubes with some other method since most of them are not used, only the extreme corner ones. Regarding the balcony, yes, I guess I will find lots of buildings where I will run inte problems but I guess I could fix these manually.